# #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'points_per_game'

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query to create a table from another larger one in phpMyAdmin mySQL. I added the round() in order to get rid of the error but have no clue how to proceed. Any help would be great!

```
CREATE TABLE above_avg_fwd AS 
    SELECT *
     FROM `playerStats`
     WHERE ROUND(`playerStats`.`COL 10`) > (SELECT AVG(`playerStats`.`COL 10`)
                                            FROM `playerStats`
                                           ) AND 
          `playerStats`.`COL 4` LIKE 'FWD';
```

Comment: it is really helpful if you mock up your situation in a website like db-fiddle.com or sql-fiddle.com. I'd go there, create your table `playerStats`, populate it with some sample data and then post the link back here. That way we know exactly how `playerStats` is formatted and we can help you get your answer quicker and easier.

Comment: Where is `points_per_game` in query?

Comment: it's COL 10 it was just what phpMyAdmin defaulted to